# Why doesn't the default libreoffice have the database 'base'?

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, snap

I have a newly installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a clean machine. I know that there are problems with local 'help' files accessed via snap but why is there no base installed with the built in Libreoffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of choice.

You can install Libre Office Base from Ubuntu Software if you require it as well as with other modules not included by default on the installation media.

Comment: It appears that you are correct, although on 2 other machines that I have (both of which started on earlier ubuntu versions) I don't remember having to install base separately. I will, however, accept this answer, thank you.